# xsl code does not return all cities

Tags: xml, xslt

The xsl code is just returning one city for each country. Any idea why? Because I was expecting get all the cities for each country.

You can see the code and the result that Im getting:

**RESULT**

```
<html>
   <ul>
      <li>United States</li>
      <li>LA</li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li>Poland</li>
      <li>Gdańsk</li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>
</html>
```

**CODE**

```
   <html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
    <xsl:for-each select="//nations">
        <xsl:for-each select="nation">
          <ul>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="nationame"/></li>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="cities/city/cityname"/></li>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="cities/city/population"/></li>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</html>

<nations>
  <nation>
    <nationame>United States</nationame>
    <cities>
      <city>
          <cityname>LA</cityname>
          <citypopulation>4000000</citypopulation>
      </city>
      <city>
          <cityname>NY</cityname>
          <citypopulation>10000000</citypopulation>
      </city>
    </cities>
  </nation>
  <nation>
    <nationame>Poland</nationame>
    <cities>
      <city>
          <cityname>Gdańsk</cityname>
          <citypopulation>40000</citypopulation>
      </city>
      <city>
          <cityname>Poznań</cityname>
          <citypopulation>100000</citypopulation>
      </city>
    </cities>
  </nation>
</nations>
```

Someone realizes why is not working?

Comment: Is there a good reason you're using the simplified stylesheet format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the string-value of the **first** node in the selected node-set. To get all the values, you need to use (another) `xsl:for-each`, for example:

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
    <xsl:for-each select="nations/nation">
        <ul>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="nationame"/></li>
            <xsl:for-each select="cities/city">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="cityname"/></li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll need another `for-each` loop to iterate through the cities. Otherwise the XSLT will match on the first city it finds

Secondly, you're calling the population incorrectly. Your XML has a `citypopulation` node, while your XSLT is referencing `population`